# Class java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException cannot be cast to class xsbti.FullReload

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to follow some tutorials to learn more about Scala and I am trying to use it in IntelliJ in my computer (MacBook Pro M1). I installed sdk using sdkman. However, I get certain errors regarding it and I don't know how to fix this.

EDIT: Following a suggestion below, more info about how I installed this:

I am trying the [Introduction to Scala course on LinkedIn Learning](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/introduction-to-scala/). I installed the community version (Apple Sillicon) of IntelliJ [available here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pt-br/idea/download/#section=mac), then Scala using the command `curl -fL https://github.com/coursier/launchers/raw/master/cs-x86_64-apple-darwin.gz | gzip -d > cs && chmod +x cs && (xattr -d com.apple.quarantine cs || true) && ./cs setup` [available here](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/). Finally, I used `curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash` and `source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"` to install SDK, following what is [available here](https://sdkman.io/install).

After all that, the error below appears when I go into terminal and write `sbt -version` or if I try to run something in IntelliJ:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException cannot be cast to class xsbti.FullReload (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; xsbti.FullReload is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at sbt.internal.XMainConfiguration.run(XMainConfiguration.java:59)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:46)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$run$1(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:176)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$apply$1(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:159)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:73)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] [launcher] error during sbt launcher: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException cannot be cast to class xsbti.FullReload (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; xsbti.FullReload is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I have no idea what this means and how to fix this. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: This is almost impossible for anyone to fix without knowing which exact steps did you take...we have no minimum example

Comment: Hi, @Dasph! Sorry for the lack of info. This is very new to me and I sincerely don't even know how to begin investigating it. I edited my question to include more info. Does that help to clarify what I did? Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6925

Comment: Hi, Seth! Thanks a lot. That seems to be my problem indeed. In your last comment there you mention that we should also update project/build.properties. Indeed, althought my sbt version is 1.7.1, my project/build.properties shows `sbt.version = 1.5.5`. How can I update those build.properties? Do I simply write there 1.7.1 in the place of the 1.5.5 and then I just reopen my project?

Comment: Yes, I simply wrote 1.7.1 in the place of 1.5.5, reopened my project and then it started to work! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 5):

Already in the comments, but to post it as an answer:

The sbt version specified under `project/build.properties` should match your actual sbt version (you can get it by running `$ sbt -version` outside your project folder).

So edit `project/build.properties` accordingly:

```
sbt.version=1.9.3
```

Answer (score 3):

You should control your java version. When i downgraded version to java 11 problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the reason was in the JDK version. After this steps it works properly.

1. Check the java version:

```
java -version
```

2. Check all the JDK installed on your Mac:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

3. Update the version:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Source: http://lertsirikarn.blogspot.com/2022/05/how-to-fix-sbt-error-error-during-sbt.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by following this instructions from the repo [xsbt](https://github.com/cjmx/xsbt)

on the modifying SBT section stating,

> If a project has project/build.properties defined, either delete the file or change sbt.version to 0.13.0-SNAPSHOT.